# Python __import__ is only giving me top level module

Tags: python, import

I'm doing

```
module = __import__("client.elements.gui.button", globals(), locals(), [], 0)
```

But it's only returning `client`.

What is my problem?

Comment: For Python 2.7 or newer, use [`importlib.import_module()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what `__import__` does.

> [When the *name* variable is of the form `package.module`, normally, the top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned, *not* the module named by *name*.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

You're not really supposed to use `__import__`; if you want to import a module dynamically, use [`importlib.import_module`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module).

Answer (score 3):

Accepted answer is correct, but if you read on in the docs you'll find that this can be gotten around with an admittedly unsettling "hack" by using `__import__` like so:

```
module = __import__('client.elements.gui.button', fromlist=[''])
```

It doesn't really matter what you pass in for `fromlist` so long as it's a non-empty list.  This signals to the default `__import__` implementation that you want to do a `from x.y.z import foo` style import, and it *will* return the the module you're after.

As stated you should use `importlib` instead, but this is still a workaround if you need to support Python versions < 2.7.

Comment: Really interesting and great supplementary answer.

Answer (score 2):

It only obtains the top level, but you can also work around this like so:

```
module_name = 'some.module.import.class'
    module = __import__(module_name)
    for n in module_name.split('.')[1:]:
        module = getattr(module, n)

# module is now equal to what would normally 
# have been retrieved where you to properly import the file
```